# Windows service created using sc.exe fails to start after reaching a timeout of 3000ms

Tags: windows, service, lighttpd

I am trying to run LightTPD server as a windows service. I created a windows service with the name ltpd using the following sc.exe command:

```
sc create ltpd binpath= C:\LightTPD\LightTPD.exe type= own start=auto
```

This successfully creates a service and shows it in the service control manager. Now when I try to start the service using the net start command or using the services manager, both of them lead to a timeout of 3000ms and are unable to start the service.

Any workarounds for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You can't just run any random executable as a service; there is a protocol it must follow.  There are some utilities that wrap this protocol around a regular executable, but I don't know how reliable they are.

Comment: I've heard good things about http://nssm.cc/

Comment: Thanks for your replies! @Luke, Now I understand that underlying protocol a service executable should follow. I did try wrapping the executable in that format too, but it led to the same error. When I tried wrapping a random console application (that I created) with the same wrapper, it worked perfectly. No idea why the LightTPD executable won't work in the same fashion